# What is the fastest way for me to take a query and turn it into a refreshable graph of the results set?

Tags: sql, reporting

I often find myself writing one off queries to either answer someone's question or trouble shoot something and I would like to be able to quickly expose the on demand refreshable results of the query graphically so that I can share these results to others without having to go through the process of creating an SSRS report and publishing it to a reporting services server.

I have thought about using excel to do this or maybe running a local SSRS server but both of these options are still labor intensive and I cannot justify the time it would take to do these since no one has officially requested that I turn this data into a report.

The way I see it the business I work for has invested money in me creating these queries that often return potentially useful data that other people in the organization might want but since it isn't exposed in any way and I don't know that this data is something they want and they may not even realize they want this data, the potential value of the query is not realized. I want to increase the company's return on investment on all these one off queries that I and other developers write by exposing their results graphically so that they can be browsed by others and then potentially turned into more formalized SSRS reports if they provide enough value to justify the development of the report.

What is the fastest way for me to take a query and turn it into a refreshable graph of the results set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you simply use what you may already have.  Excel...you can import data via an ODBC / Oracle / SQL Connection.  Get Data..and bam you can run the query and format it right in the spreadsheet and provide sorting etc.  All you need to supply is the database name and user name and password to connect to the db.

Comment: Basically as Anthony already pointed out this is cumbersome to share as I would have to configure an odbc connection on each user's computer who I want to be able to see the data which is not feasible for a throw away query that no one officially wants to see the results of.

Comment: @OligatoryMoniker - I think you have it a bit wrong, this is not cumbersome as you do not need to go to each end user pc.  This can be scripted.

Answer (score 1):

JonH is right regarding Excel's built in ODBC support, but I have had tons of trouble with this. In my case, the ODBC connection required the client software to be installed so that it could use the encryption methods, etc. Also, even if that were not the case, the user (I believe) would still have to manually install and set up an ODBC connection.

Now if you just want something on your machine to do the queries and refresh them, JohH's solution is great and my caveats are probably irrelavent. But if you want other users to have access, you should consider having a middle-man app (basically a PHP script, assuming a web server is an option for you), that does a query, transforms the results into XML, and outputs it as "report-xyz.xml". You can then point anybody running a newer version of Excel to that address and they can very easily import the data into Excel with no overhead. (basically a kind of web service).

Keep in mind, I **don't** think you should have a web script that will allow users to make queries to your Database server! You would have some admin page where you make pass the query in and a new xml file with the results gets made. So my idea is also based on the idea that you want to run the same queries over and over without any specifics passed in. (if that were the case, I'd look into just finding a pre-built web services bridge for your database that already has security features built in. Then you could have users make the limited changes allowed.)